# Node JS works on localhost, online 404

Tags: ajax, node.js, post, http-status-code-404

So i am trying to publish an node js app , but it is returning me 404 for my post calls . It works perfectly on localhost. This is my code :

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');  
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');


var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app); 

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));  
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users); 



server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000,function(){
    console.log("Working on " + process.env.PORT);
});


module.exports = app;
```

This is my routes index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request'); 
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var router = express.Router();
var app = express();

var jsonParser = bodyParser.json() 
app.use(bodyParser.json())


var Connection = require('tedious').Connection; 
var databaseConnection
var config = {}


var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;  
var config = {  
    userName: 'asdasd',  
    password: 'password',  
    server: 'server',   
    options: {encrypt: true, database: 'asdasd'}  
};  
var connection = new Connection(config);  
connection.on('connect', function(err) {   
    console.log("Connected");  
});  


router.post('/call',jsonParser, function(req,res){ 
   res.send('someresponse')
}
```

I am simply calling /call through ajax , but it keeps throwing 404 not found.
What am i doing wrong ? It doesnt make sense to me to work on localhost but not online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my auto generated web config was not doing its job , i have swaped it with another one i found on internet

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps

Just changed from server.js to app.js

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express you cann start server directly with express.

```
app.listen(port)
```

If you want to do it with nodejs http you also have to set the port nodejs should listen to.

[nodejs http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html)

[express app.listen](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.listen)

Comment: Can you be more precise about what i should do , i could just add app.listen(process.env.PORT) ?

Comment: this is one posibility, if you set envirement variables. But you can also use only app.listen(8080) as an example

Comment: Hmm jeah , still no help , after adding app.listen or server.listen and restarting my web app , i still get 404 on my calls

Comment: do you run start server with 'node app.js'?

Comment: I am pushing my application to web application online , i am starting my server automaticly with package.json if i am not wrong.

Comment: and you have to export router not the app.js. also all you configuration you do index.js could be done in app.js so they are avalible in the hole app

Comment: if you have somethin like start: 'node app.js' in your package.json you also have to start it with npm start. what do you mean with 'web apllication online'?

Comment: I am pretty sure server is starting , problem is i am getting 404 , this application works fine when run on localhost through node , but when i put it online on my web application(web site , web page) i am getting 404 for all posts i am trying to access.

Comment: the port you are using is not blocked on your server? You get no error messages back when you start the server?

Comment: It was web config , even tho it was generated it self , it looked at server.js instead of app.js